# typedef with function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

I want to transfer a function pointer in the constructor but get some error Messages...

I my parent class I declared:

```
class Strip{

public:
     typedef void(Strip::*LOG)(const std::string&);
```

with a function `log(const string&)`

In my child class I forward declare Strip with `class Strip` and have somthing like that

```
class Observable{

public:

  Observable(const char &signal,Strip::LOG log,const QCustomPlot *plot);
```

with a parameter

```
Strip::LOG log;
```

When I try to compile I get the error's

Strip::LOG has not been declared
and LOG in class Strip does not name a type

Any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: Forward declaring the class only lets you use a pointer to the class itself, not any types declared within. You might need to include the .h into your second file.

Comment: `typedef void(Strip::*LOG)(const std::string&);` is not visible in your child class.

Comment: a) use C++ [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of C style function pointers b) when gathering a pointer to member use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to ensure the call can be made correctly.

Comment: In class Strip: `typedef void(*LOG)(const std::string&);` some compilers wouldn't like the `Strip::*LOG` in the class declaration.

Comment: @KarthikT. Should I include it in there since the parent has already included the header of the child. I once heard that this is not advisable. Or am I to caughtios here

Comment: @Mgetz. Thank you I didn't know anything about function & mem_fn I'll try it you're way now. My problem is that `function<void(const std::string&)> logFun = log;` within the class Stripe gives me an `conversion from <unresolved overloaded function type>` error. And If I use `auto logFun = mem_fn(&Strip::log);` I get the type `_Mem_fn<(Strip::*)(const string &)>` which I cannot give over the constructor. Any help on the syntax would be appreciated. thx magu_

Comment: @SHR gcc didn't complain, but I guess it's bad practice anyway then.

Comment: @magu_ what are you trying to achieve? It would seem easier to me to make `Strip` implement an Interface and pass that in the form of a pointer to `Observable` ([unless `Observable` is intended to own it](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) ).

Comment: @Mgetz No it doesn't need to own it. How would you do such an Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So passing a pointer to a member function presents several issues:

1. It's a member function as such it will need to have an instance of the class passed into it to work (the implicit `this` parameter).
2. It doesn't prevent the class you're passing it to from knowing about the class the function pointer originates so you gain nothing in terms of hiding.

A better way is to declare an Interface and pass that

```
// ILogger.hpp
// should be completely virtual
struct ILogger{
    virtual void log(const ::std::string&) = 0;
};

// Strip.cpp
class Strip : public ILogger{
public:
    void log(const ::std::string& data){
        // does something
    }
};


// Observable.cpp
#include "ILogger.hpp"
class Observable{
public:
    Observable(ILogger* logger);
};


// some other file that knows about and constructs both

// has to be a pointer allocated to new to make the Vtables work
::std::unique_ptr<Strip> s(new Strip());

// pass in the pointer to an instance of a class that implements ILogger
Observable observed(s.get());
```

Using an interface means you can completely abstract the two classes apart and `Observable` need not know anything about the instance being passed to it other than it implements `ILogger`. Internally `Observable` can call the logger by just calling `logger->log`.

Comment: Ah OK thank you. I keep forgetting the multiple inheritance thing in C++. This would defenetly be the cleanest solution. Thank you for your help

Comment: @magu_ because the interface is pure this isn't really multiple inheritance so it avoids almost all of the issues with actual multiple inheritance.

Comment: I did forget to mention that Observable will be a Baseclass which will be derived further, plus it is already a derived class. What do you mean with pure, purely virtual. Like an abstract class or an interface in the java sense?

Comment: @magu_ I meant pure virtual, so it satisfies the same requirements as an interface in java (you can inherit from multiple interfaces in java, just not multiple classes)

Answer (score 0):

May be this code can be usefull (compiled w/o errors):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Strip{
public:
    typedef void(Strip::*LOG)(const std::string&);
    void log(const string& s)
    {
        cout << "log() called\n";
    }     
};

class Observable{
public:
    Observable( Strip::LOG l )
    {
        Strip s; 
        (s.*l)("string");
    }
};

int main() {
    Strip::LOG log = &Strip::log;
    Observable o( log );
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/RD4K1r

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As far as I understood you're answer I would need to create an other instance of Strip. The problem is that the function log accesses some properties of Strip (namely Qt gui stuff - but I can't use Qt in Stripe and Observable...). I hand the child a pointer to the parent, but I feel that this would be bad practice. Is there a way to do this without creating a new instance of the class?

Comment: @magu_ You can pass Strip instanse to Observable class instead of creation of new Strip object like in my example.